# nth-of-type selection not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

So I have 7 divs with the class test. I want divs 1-3 to be red and divs 5-7 blue. I managed to get 1-3 working but not the latter.

I would appreciate if someone would tell me how this works because it seems I don't really grasp the concept here. So how does this work?

```css
.test:nth-of-type(-n+3) {
  background: red;
}
.test:nth-of-type(-4n+3) {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
<div class="test">5</div>
<div class="test">6</div>
<div class="test">7</div>
```

I also tried `-2n + 3`, `-7n + 3`, `-4n + 7`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nth-last-of-type` when start at the end

`nth-of-type(-n+3)` means start from 0 (`n`) and move 3 items (`+3`) and then cycle backwards (`-`), which will target the first 3 items.

When you use `nth-last-of-type(-n+3)` means the same thing, it just starts at the last item.

```css
.test {
  height: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}

.test:nth-of-type(-n+3) {
    background: red;
}

.test:nth-last-of-type(-n+3) {
    background: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: It works but how does the logic work? So it counts backwards? Is it like a reverse loop?

Comment: @Asperger You can say that. `-n` means start from 0 and `+3` means 3 items. `nth-last-of-type` starts at then end.

Comment: Ah I see. So that means its impossible to start somewhere in the middle and go from there right?

Comment: In a matter of fact, reverse looping through the array is faster than looping from the beginning in most cases

Comment: @Asperger Yes. When you use the (-n+3) form it means a cycle that either go forwards or backwards.

Answer (score 3):

-4n+3 doesn't match the range 5–7. It only matches the third element and nothing else.

If you always want the last three elements, you can use `:nth-last-of-type(-n+3)` instead (which mirrors your `:nth-of-type(-n+3)` for the first three elements).

Note that `.test:nth-of-type(...)` probably doesn't mean what you think it means — you may want to qualify your selectors with `div` to make it clearer [what it actually does](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#nth-of-type-pseudo).

Comment: It works but how does the logic work? So it counts backwards? Is it like a reverse loop?

Comment: @Asperger: A negative value of n, plus a certain number (let's say x), selects only the first x elements in :nth-of-type(), and only the last x elements in :nth-last-of-type(). So yes, you can think of it like a reverse loop.